# Prevent $scope from overriding

Tags: angularjs

I am using a controller to set the icon image for each list in my ng-repeat directive. Right now the $scope.icon_level overrides all the other values with the last value given to the scope. How can I make sure each list gets it's own $scope.icon_level value and it is not replaced with the next value?

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
<li ng-repeat="exemplifier in exemplifiers | orderBy:'-average_score' | limitTo:3" ng-class="exemplifier.section"><a href="#"><img ng-src="{{icon_level}}" width="30" class="{{exemplifier.section}}"/>{{exemplifier.exemplifier}}</a></li>  
</ul>
```

How I set the scope value:

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp').controller('keyCtrl', function ($scope, dummyData) {

var exemplifiers = dummyData.exemplifier_data;

for (var i = 0; i < exemplifiers.length; i++) { 
        if(exemplifiers[i].average_score < 3) {
            $scope.icon_level = "images/acorn-icon@2x.png";
        }
        else if(exemplifiers[i].average_score < 6) {
            $scope.icon_level = "images/seedling-icon@2x.png";
        }
        else if(exemplifiers[i].average_score < 9) {
            $scope.icon_level = "images/tree-icon@2x.png";
        }
}
});
```

Comment: I was going to work out a couple options that would solve you issue, but I'm having a hard time, since your example doesn't really make sense.  first, you are iterating over `exemplifier_data` in your controller but `exemplifiers` in your HTML (one would assume that `exemplifiers` is on `$scope`, but it doesn't appear to match).  Second, your comparison variable `ringToHighlight` seems to be some value unrelated to the `exemplifier_data` that would be the same for every iteration?

Comment: did you end up solving your issue? curious which route you took to a solution.

Comment: @Claies thank you! This worked. The first option (:

Answer (score 0):

Because of the complexity of the 3 conditions - ng-src is probably not best. so I gave you an easier, ng-if based solution. the non-applicable images will not render in the DOM. I am making the assumption that `ringToHighlight` is an property of `exemplifier`

HTML

```
    <li ng-repeat="exemplifier in exemplifiers | orderBy:'-average_score' |"+
               " limitTo:3" ng-class="exemplifier.section">
        <a href="#">
<img ng-if="exemplifier.ringToHighlight <3" src="images/acorn-icon@2x.png" width="30" class="{{exemplifier.section}}"/>
<img ng-if="exemplifier.ringToHighlight >= 3 && exemplifier.ringToHighlight < 6" src="images/seedling-icon@2x.png" width="30" class="{{exemplifier.section}}"/>
<img ng-if="exemplifier.ringToHighlight >= 6 && exemplifier.ringToHighlight < 9" src="images/tree-icon@2x.png" width="30" class="{{exemplifier.section}}"/>
{{exemplifier.exemplifier}}
        </a>
    </li>
```

JS

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp').controller('keyCtrl', function ($scope, dummyData) {

var exemplifier_data = dummyData.exemplifier_data;
$scope.exemplifiers = exemplifier_data;

});
```

Comment: I get this error: 
GET http://localhost:9000/[%22images/acorn-icon@2x.png%22,%22images/seedling-ic…2x.png%22,%22images/seedling-icon@2x.png%22,%22images/tree-icon@2x.png%22] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: btw - where is your $scope.exemplifiers that you're repeating on?

Comment: Is that what exemplifier_data is supposed to be?

Comment: Awesome. And where do you define ringToHighlight? I am building an ng-src for you :-)

Comment: I would be cautious about using `$index` for this purpose.  `$index` doesn't represent the object's `index` in it's parent array, it represents it's position in the `ng-repeat`, which may change due to filters applied.  I suspect this will give inconsistent results.

Comment: @itamar I just edited my code to hopefully make it easier to understand.

Comment: Agreed, @Claies - I changed the solution to an ng-if based one because of the complexity of the condition.

Comment: @user5694093 - check out my new solution. I think it's simpler.

Comment: @itamar thanks. Did you check out my edited code? I don't think this will work with my new code.

Comment: @user5694093 I see your new code. If exemplifiers is not in the $scope - you can't ng-repeat on it, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 'ng-class' and assign the style to the tag as you iterate.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("main",["$scope",function($scope){
  
  $scope.ids =[{"id":"bob", "value": 3},{ "id": "fred","value": 1},{"id":"mark", "value": 5},{"id":"sally", "value": 3}];
  
  $scope.exemplifiers = $scope.ids.map(function(e){ 
    if( e.value > 3) {e.section = "red"; }
    else if( e.value > 1 ){ e.section = "blue";} 
    else {e.section = "green";} 
    return e;  
  });
  
  
  }]);
```

```css
.green {
  background-color:green;
  /* replace with your imgs */ 
  }
.red { 
  background-color:red;
  /* replace with your imgs */
  }
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
 }
img.green{
  content:url("images/acorn-icon@2x.png");
        }

img.red{
content:url(images/seedling-icon@2x.png";
        }
        
img.blue{
content:url("images/tree-icon@2x.png"
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="main" > 
  <ul> 
    <li ng-repeat="exemplifier in exemplifiers" >{{exemplifier.id}}
    <img ng-class="exemplifier.section" alt="{{exemplifier.section}}" /></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve the problem you are describing here.  The root of the problem boils down to the fact that you want to represent multiple values in your HTML but you have only allocated a single variable.

Angular's two way binding is going to ensure that this value always stays up to date, meaning that your iteration is essentially looping through the whole array and resetting the same variable to a new value over and over, and your result will always be the last item in the loop.

There are two common ways to approach this problem.  One way would be to create a property on each `exemplifier` and attach the value to this object property.  If augmenting your objects is not possible or causes other issues, an alternative would be to change the `icon_level` into a function that can be run repeatedly and return different results each time.

**Option 1:**

Here we loop through the `exemplifiers` and add an additional `icon_level` property to each.  Note, I also am illustrating the use of [`angular.foreach()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) here.

```js
var exemplifiers = dummyData.exemplifier_data;

angular.foreach(exemplifiers, function(exemplifier) {
  if (exemplifier.average_score < 3) {
    exemplifier.icon_level = "images/acorn-icon@2x.png";
  } else if (exemplifier.average_score < 6) {
    exemplifier.icon_level = "images/seedling-icon@2x.png";
  } else if (exemplifier.average_score < 9) {
    exemplifier.icon_level = "images/tree-icon@2x.png";
  }
});
```

```html
<li ng-repeat="exemplifier in exemplifiers | orderBy:'-average_score' | limitTo:3" ng-class="exemplifier.section">
  <a href="#">
    <img ng-src="{{exemplifier.icon_level}}" width="30" class="{{exemplifier.section}}" />{{exemplifier.exemplifier}}</a>
</li>
```

**Option 2:**

Here, we convert `$scope.icon_level` into a function, and call it for each `ng-repeat` iteration, passing in the value that we want to check.

```js
$scope.icon_level = function(level) {
  if (level < 3) {
    return "images/acorn-icon@2x.png";
  } else if (level < 6) {
    return "images/seedling-icon@2x.png";
  } else if (level < 9) {
    return "images/tree-icon@2x.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<li ng-repeat="exemplifier in exemplifiers | orderBy:'-average_score' | limitTo:3" ng-class="exemplifier.section">
  <a href="#">
    <img ng-src="icon_level(exemplifier.average_score)" width="30" class="{{exemplifier.section}}" />{{exemplifier.exemplifier}}</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by doing using ng-style and setting the scope variable in each view controller:

JS:

```
<body ng-app="ciscoImaDashboardApp" ng-controller="navCtrl" ng-style="{'background-image': backgroundImg}" >
```

HTML:

```
$rootScope.backgroundImg = "url('../images/background-bark@2x.jpg')";
```